# Conflicting CSS

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I want to use this CSS and HTML http://jsfiddle.net/6VntE/ but many of the selectors are conflicting with previously used selectors (body, H1, div). So while it works in jfiddle, it doesn't work in my site.

Is there a way to section off this css from the rest of the site so that it will work?

Comment: what u want ?............ post your site link

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to apply a css style to apply on All div then you should use classes or id to design element instead of using tag name.

Suppose If you are doing like this

```
h1{font-size:10x;}
```

then it will style all the **h1** , but if you want to design only some elements
then write

```
.style_h1{font-size:10px;}
```

and to your **h1** tag which to be styled add `class="style_h1"`

**OR**

add a parent to your **h1** with some class called parent and then inside that design all h1

```
.parent h1{font-size:10px;}
```

and to your **h1** tags add a parent element having class parent

Comment: `h1` is a terrible class name